# Why does my theme's JS require that jquery.min.js be called from the theme's .info file?

Tags: theming, javascript

My jQuery Update gives 1.12
and my theme has 1.12
but I can't make Drupal and the theme's JS use just one instance of it. If I don't include my theme's jQuery in the .info file, the theme doesn't work.

I've tried replacing it with template.php. That results in only one loaded but only the theme's JS works.

```
function abc_js_alter(&$javascript) {
    $javascript['sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.12/jquery.min.js']['data'] = 'sites/all/themes/abc/jquery.min.js';
}
```

I've tried preprocess_html. Same thing.

I've tried making sure the theme's JS is loaded at the bottom of the page in html.tpl.php so it's definitely after jQuery Update's file.

Is there some tenet of Drupal I'm missing here? This wasn't an issue apart from page size until now as having both files breaks an Ajax form I need.

Thanks

Comment: Is your theme's js built using Drupal behaviors? Otherwise it migt execute too soon: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/understanding-javascript-behaviors-in-drupal

Comment: It isn't unfortunately. It's just some dashboard JS unrelated to Drupal so I think it will be easier to just rewrite it and do it properly.

Comment: If you read that other link, you might be able to wrap 2 lines around your existing code (but without your code it is hard to tell)